# Need to reconstruct a text effect in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I accidentally rendered a Layer Style into Layers in Photoshop. Can someone in here help me reconstructing the same effect? I need it for another title but I can't figure out how to apply some of the effects again. The overall color is working but it is especially the Embossed effects that are hard to construct.

I will share the PSD-file if that could help me get a bit closer that I've made so far. Thanks.

[image]

Here are the Embossed Layers isolated on the background.
[image]

Comment: Looks like you used some combination of Pillow Emboss, possibly also an inner stroke.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have layered two differently embossed versions:

1. In the bottom a version which makes those fine metallic edges (I cannot see the exact settings for the same edges)

[image]

2. Another, which creates larger colored areas:

[image]

After making the large color area version partially transparent and giving the color to the metallic edge version with a blending mode, you have both the edges and colors:

[image]